# Differentiate under integral sign

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

> Let $f$ is function with continuous derivatives, such that $f(\sqrt{2})=2$ and for any real numbers $x$,
>   $$f(x)=\lim_{t \to 0}{\dfrac{1}{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}sf'(s)ds}.$$

I have tried but not able able to get the correct solution by Leibniz's Rule but got correct answer by " Fundamental Theorem Of Calculus ".Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Please restate the first sentence. It doesn't make much sense as it stands.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 4):

Note that by the [Fundamental Theorem Of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus),
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{1}{2t}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}sf'(s)ds&=
\dfrac{1}{2}\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{1}{t}\int_{x}^{x+t}sf'(s)ds
+\dfrac{1}{2}\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{1}{(-t)}\int_{x}^{x-t}sf'(s)ds\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}xf'(x)+\dfrac{1}{2}xf'(x)=xf'(x).
\end{align*}
Hence $f$ solves the differential equation $f(x)=xf'(x)$ which implies $f(x)=cx$ with $c\in\mathbb{R}$.
By using the initial condition $f(\sqrt{2})=2$ we obtain that $f(x)=\sqrt{2}x$.

Comment: How can this help?

Comment: @MyGlasses Is it better now?

Comment: The last equality in the set of equations should just be $f(x)$, no?

Comment: @Harry Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use Hospital rule and with [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)
$$f(x)=\lim_{t \to 0}\dfrac{\int_{x-t}^{x+t}sf'(s)ds}{2t}=\dfrac{xf'(x)+xf'(x)}{2}=xf'(x)$$

Comment: Nice approach +1.